# Apache Camel: consume a rest service with jetty

Tags: java, apache-camel, jetty

I want consum a rest service in http://localhost:8080/ with apache-camel using jetty. But this code not produce any request to the API. I am beginner in apache-camel and I want use to orchestation of differents microservices.

Code:

```
package example;

import org.apache.camel.CamelContext;
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext;



public class ejemplo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {



        CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();
        context.setTracing(true);
        context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder(){

            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {

                from("direct:start")
                .log("Http Route started")
                .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD,simple("GET"))
                .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,simple("application/json"))
                .to("jetty:http://0.0.0.0:8080/")
                .process(new Processor(){

                    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                        System.out.println("I am a process....");
                        String msg = exchange.getIn().getBody().toString();
                        System.out.println(msg);

                    }

                });

            }

        });

        context.start();

    }

}
```

Log:

```
sep 24, 2019 7:57:05 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext start
INFORMACIÓN: Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) is starting
sep 24, 2019 7:57:05 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartCamel
INFORMACIÓN: Tracing is enabled on CamelContext: camel-1
sep 24, 2019 7:57:05 PM org.apache.camel.management.ManagedManagementStrategy doStart
INFORMACIÓN: JMX is enabled
sep 24, 2019 7:57:05 PM org.apache.camel.impl.converter.DefaultTypeConverter doStart
INFORMACIÓN: Loaded 208 type converters
sep 24, 2019 7:57:05 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultRuntimeEndpointRegistry doStart
INFORMACIÓN: Runtime endpoint registry is in extended mode gathering usage statistics of all incoming and outgoing endpoints (cache limit: 1000)
sep 24, 2019 7:57:05 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartCamel
INFORMACIÓN: AllowUseOriginalMessage is enabled. If access to the original message is not needed, then its recommended to turn this option off as it may improve performance.
sep 24, 2019 7:57:05 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartCamel
INFORMACIÓN: StreamCaching is not in use. If using streams then its recommended to enable stream caching. See more details at http://camel.apache.org/stream-caching.html
sep 24, 2019 7:57:05 PM org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Log initialized
INFORMACIÓN: Logging initialized @1372ms
sep 24, 2019 7:57:06 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext doStartOrResumeRouteConsumers
INFORMACIÓN: Route: route1 started and consuming from: Endpoint[direct://httpRouter]
sep 24, 2019 7:57:06 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext start
INFORMACIÓN: Total 1 routes, of which 1 are started.
sep 24, 2019 7:57:06 PM org.apache.camel.impl.DefaultCamelContext start
INFORMACIÓN: Apache Camel 2.17.1 (CamelContext: camel-1) started in 1.466 seconds
```

This output not produces any response of the API in localhost:8080 but I think that the route is correct. I would want know if there are other ways of consume a rest service of a API REST using apache-camel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that `start` is just a name and `direct` component allows you to invoke your route synchronously from other route, it seems like you are not doing just that

To check if the route is correct replace `direct` in your from endpoint to `timer`, e.g. `from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=10000")`, for more details see [camel docs](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/timer-component.html)

Comment: I am trying solve the problem with this solucion but the result is the same than previous moment.

Comment: `timer` should run your route every amount of time you have specified, it is 10 seconds in the example above, so now you could debug the code, for instance, if "Http Route started" appears in log?

Comment: INFORMACIÓN: Http Route started
CamelHttpMethod=GET, CamelHttpResponseCode=200, Content-Length=11, Content-Type=text/plain;charset=UTF-8, Date=Wed, 25 Sep 2019 12:04:08 GMT, firedTime=Wed Sep 25 14:04:08 CEST 2019}, BodyType:byte[], Body:Hello World
sep 25, 2019 2:04:18 PM org.apache.camel.util.CamelLogger log

The rest call is received but i cant print the msg to screen. How I can catch the rest service?

Comment: I would try `convertBodyTo(String.class)` before response processing